# Spring : treat model variable as JS inside JSP

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jstl

I am using spring MVC. Inside controller I am setting a model value as below:

```
public class myClassObj{
   private String firstName;
   ..
   // setter getter
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value = "path")
public String getPostGallery(ModelMap model) throws ContentDeletedException
{
    model.addAttribute("data",myClassObj);
    return "myPage";
}
```

Now inside `myPage.jsp` I have a function `show(d)` :

```
function show(d){
  $.each(d,function(k,v){});
}
```

If i call `show(data)` inside AJAX it iterate & display data correctly. but if I pass args as `${}` it doesn't.

Is it possible to call `show("${data}")` and `${data}` will be treated as JSON or js object?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to set the variable in pageContext using

```
<c:set var="name" value="${variableNameFromController}"/>
```

and then in js you can use that variable using EL-Syntax or expression language.